# Stop default notification that load in notification tray when app is killed?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am receiving my data in background and through zzE method I m populating my custom notification, but with that custom notification, the default notification also pops up. I want to stop that? Can you please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Which payload are you sending? Could you give some more details?

Comment: data payload this is I am receiving

Comment: I think you are sending both types of payload notification and data payload. If you are not sending both then share your code.

Comment: @UmarFarooq what json do you send over push?

Comment: I am only sending data payload notificaiton

Comment: @EduardoHerzer { "data":{"order_id":12}} this is my json coming from FCM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `onMessageReceived` method if you receiving through zzE method.